# Wix Toolset: cannot add Excel Add-in project reference

Tags: wix, excel-addins

I've just installed latest Wix v3.7. I created a VS 2010 "Excel 2010 Add-in" project and, in the same solution, a Wix "Setup Project".

Problem is, when I try to reference the Add-in project from the Wix project, it is not there,

[image]

I tried a simple console app, and in that case works well.

Question - why the reference to the Add-in project cannot be added? Any fix or workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i would try to uninstall. or report it into their forums. read this as well http://mgrowan.wordpress.com/2008/01/09/wix-installation-for-excel-add-in/

Comment: try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16279617/47432

Comment: @Ariel, have you managed to get it working yet? Please let us know if so!

Comment: this issue has been reported to wix bug list: http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4337/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a WiX problem; you cannot add a reference to VSTO Addin project in general. You could try that with any other (non-WiX) type of project - same result.

The problem is that VSTO project were specifically disabled to be added as references. For whatever reason, hail Microsoft.

Was changed (fixed?) in VSTO 2013 Update 3. After updating VSTO, you should be able to add references now.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2014/08/04/visual-studio-2013-update-3-released.aspx, item #3